# PHP RegExp revert assertion to get the opposite match

Tags: php, regex

this is my first question so please be nice :). I'm trying to build a regexp to get an array of IPs that are both valid (OK, at least with the proper IPv4 format) and NOT a private IP according to RFC 1918. So far, I've figured out a way to get exactly the opposite, I mean succcssfuly matching private IPs, so all what I need is a way to revert the assertion. This is the code so far:

```
// This is an example string
$ips = '10.0.1.23, 192.168.1.2, 172.24.2.189, 200.52.85.20, 200.44.85.20';

preg_match_all('/(?:10\.\d{1,3}|172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[01])|192\.168)\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', $ips, $matches);

print_r($matches);

// Prints:
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [0] => 10.0.1.23
    [1] => 192.168.1.2
    [2] => 172.24.2.189
  )
)
```

And what I want as result is:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [0] => 200.52.85.20
    [1] => 200.44.85.20
  )
)
```

I've tried changing the first part of the expression (the lookahead) to be negative (?!) but this messes up the results and don't even switch the result.

If you need any more informartion please feel free to ask, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Arent you missing a paranthesis in your regex for the first noncapture group?

Comment: Don't think so, if you look carefully there are two closing parenthesis: [01]) and 168).

Comment: You get a +1 for me just for posting code and clearly stating your question :). This is tougher than it looked. I did come up with a solution that splits the string and then checks each IP individually. Not an exact answer to the question. Let me know if you'd like me to post it.

Comment: Thanks Cfreak. Actually my current code does pretty much that; it splits the string, then I use a reduced version of the expression and ip2long() to discard non-valid and private IPs, however being a perfectionistic I wanted to save at least one pass. If that's impossible (there's really no way to invert the assertion??), looking into filter_var() seems to be the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is to exclude a relatively small range of ip's, you could do this
(if I didn't make any typo's):

```
/(?!\b(?:10\.\d{1,3}|172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[01])|192\.168)\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)/
```

Example in Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @found = '10.0.1.23, 192.168.1.2, 172.24.2.189, 200.52.85.20, 200.44.85.20' =~
/
(?!
   \b
   (?:
        10\.\d{1,3}
      |
        172\.
        (?:
            1[6-9]
          | 2\d
          | 3[01]
        )
      |
        192\.168
   )
   \.\d{1,3}
   \.\d{1,3}
   \b
)
\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)
/xg;

for (@found) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Output:

200.52.85.20
200.44.85.20

Comment: Many thanks sir, that's exactly what I asked for, so you get my vote. However, I'm still using the tip from Matteo to do the actual validation. Too bad you can't vote for two answers!

Answer (score 4):

There is a PHP function for that: [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php).  Check these constants: `FILTER_FLAG_IPV4`, `FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE`.

However if you still want to solve this with regular expressions, I suggest you split your problem in two parts: first you extract all the IP addresses, then you filter out the private ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks very promising. What would be the easiest way to use the filter against the string? I don't think I can include it in the regexp, right?

Comment: You pull whatever *looks like* an IP address and pass it through that function.